# Move product title above product image on Woocommerce archive pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to move the product title above the product image on the product archive page. I have managed to figure out how to move the information, but the price is moving above the image aswell.

I want only the product title to be above the product image. The price should remain below, with the add to cart button etc.

Here is my code snippet and screenshot of result so far:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead try the following, where you will set the product thumbnail just after the product title:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 11 );
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

It should work for you too.

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly, slight change I was missing! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code

Please change the code in below file

wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-product.php

OR

wp-content/theme/yourtheme/woocommerce/templates/content-product.php

```
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' );
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
    do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );
```

Replace it

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' );
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );
```