# Display Woocommerce attribute name above product title

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

On the Woocommerce 'shop' page I have the product description below the main image.

Underneath that, I have the range name which I managed to display using the 'WooCommerce Show Attributes' plugin. What I want however is to display the range name above the product title.

Attached is an image of how it looks at the moment.

How can I achieve this?

[image: product example]

```
<figure class="woocom-project">
<div class="woo-buttons-on-img">

    <a href="#" class="alignnone layzr-bg-transparent"></a>     

</div>
<figcaption class="woocom-list-content">

                <h4 class="entry-title">
            <a href="#" title="product description" rel="bookmark">product description</a>
        </h4>
    <span class="custom-attributes"><span class="range alma"><span class="attribute-value">range name,</span></span><br></span>
<span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>838.00</span></span>
 abc123

</figcaption>
```

Comment: Is this post what you're looking to do? The code would go in your `functions.php` file: [Move product title above product image on Woocommerce archive pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51623262/move-product-title-above-product-image-on-woocommerce-archive-pages)

Comment: No, it's not the product title I want to move, but the name of the product attribute that I set for each one. This needs to sit just above the product title. I guess it would be a similar process but I am new to woocommerce and editing the functions.php file

Comment: Without seeing your website it's hard to know what to recommend. It looks like you're building your project from scratch using custom code instead of the woocommerce plugin...not sure why. Woocommerce products are shown in an unordered list that starts with `<ul class="products">` and the code in the linked post would control which data is shown where. Here are a couple of useful links:

[What is: functions.php](https://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/functions-php/) ; 
[How to Create a WordPress Child Theme](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-wordpress-child-theme-video/)