# How to move the title on above product image when the plugin WooCommerce Blocks is active

Tags: php, wordpress

So i have a problem on regards the woo commerce. I want to move the title above the product image on both shop page and the featured product. I'm currently using WooCommerce Blocks (https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-gutenberg-products-block/). but apparently the code i'm using from this page is not working. [Move product title above product image on Woocommerce archive pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51623262/move-product-title-above-product-image-on-woocommerce-archive-pages)

[Move product title above product image on Woocommerce archive pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51623262/move-product-title-above-product-image-on-woocommerce-archive-pages)

```php
function my_plugin_init() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 11 );
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'my_plugin_init' );
```

Before
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGGSH.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gT9j.jpg

After
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zpa90.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XHma.jpg

Comment: this code worked. 

remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 11 );

Now the problem is that the product category is not moving above the product image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the relevant Woocommerce template into a woocommerce file in the root of your theme.

This is the file you want to copy: /plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-product.php
This is where you will need to place the copy: wp-content/themes/your-theme/content-product.php

Now move

```
     /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_title - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );
```

above

```
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
```

Comment: thanks @shado. The problem now is the product category is not moving above. :( https://imgur.com/6AvVHWB

Comment: Look through the template and find that part to move.

Comment: My pleasure. Glad it helped.